# Why does `io_submit` call cause a crash on my Red Hat 7 machine?

Tags: c++, linux, oracle, io

I am trying to run a script that involves Async I/O and some interaction with an Oracle DB. For some reason the `io_submit` calls crashes, as opposed to other Asynch I/O calls.

I run a trace that gave the following:

```
28501 open("/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/dbs/snapcf_orcl.f", 
O_RDWR|O_DSYNC|O_DIRECT) = 11
28501 fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)    = 0
28501 getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=64*1024, rlim_max=64*1024}) = 0
28501 fcntl(11, F_DUPFD, 256)           = 256
28501 fcntl(256, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)   = 0
28501 close(11)                         = 0
28501 getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, {ru_utime={tv_sec=1, tv_usec=139355}, ru_stime=    {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=420103}, ...}) = 0
28501 io_submit(0x7fefef666000, 13, [{aio_data=0x7fefe9265840,         aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe9057000,         aio_nbytes=1032192, aio_offset=16384}, {aio_data=0x7fefe9265ae0, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe8f47000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=1048576}, {aio_data=0x7fefe9265d80, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe9567000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=2097152}, {aio_data=0x7fefe9266020, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe9457000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=3145728}, {aio_data=0x7fefe92662c0, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe9347000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=4194304}, {aio_data=0x7fefe9266560, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe9747000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=5242880}, {aio_data=0x7fefe9266800, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe9947000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=6291456}, {aio_data=0x7fefe9266aa0, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe8c97000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=7340032}, {aio_data=0x7fefe9266d40, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe8da7000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=8388608}, {aio_data=0x7fefe9266fe0, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe7f47000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=9437184}, {aio_data=0x7fefe9267280, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe8057000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=10485760}, {aio_data=0x7fefe9267520, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe8167000, aio_nbytes=1048576, aio_offset=11534336}, {aio_data=0x7fefe92677c0, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PREAD, aio_fildes=256, aio_buf=0x7fefe8277000, aio_nbytes=999424, aio_offset=12582912}]) = 13
28501 times(NULL)                       = 604513619
28501 --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x80} ---
```

I am looking for pointers on possible areas where I can start looking for errors, since I am new to system programming

the script portion involving io_submit looks something like this:

```
typedef int (*real_io_submit)(io_context_t, long, struct iocb **);

int io_submit(io_context_t ctx_id, long nr, struct iocb **iocbpp) {
   // some business logic
   return ((real_io_submit)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "io_submit"))(ctx_id, nr, iocbpp);
}
```

Comment: Possible reason: 100000 lines of code earlier the program invoked undefined behaviour, mortally wounding the program, bit it staggered on and it finally fell over and died at a perfectly-innocent `io_submit`.

Comment: Why are you aliasing the io_submit in the aio library? What happens if you don't do that?

Comment: @user4581301 yeah that's also possible. Any way I can make sure that io_submit is responsible?

Comment: Use `gdb` to find the exact location of the problem.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy the problem is the program is a shared library that I wrote and it is used by Oracle Recovery manager. Can I run gdb on the shared library and intercept calls to that library?

Comment: Compile it with debug and no optimization.